# Property of a recursively generated sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems

Define the sequence {$q_n$} as

$$ q_i=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
q_i & =a_i & i\leq m \\
q_i & =\sum_{j=1}^mc_jq_{i+j-m-1} & i\gt m
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

where $a_i\in\mathbb{R}/\{0\}$ and $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$, for $i=1,2,...,m$. Intuitively speaking, the above definition says that from the (m+1)th term on, $q_n$ is defined as a certain linear combination of its m immediate precursors.

Now, one may expect {$q_n$} to be bounded or unbounded, convergent or divergent depending on the choice of $a$ and $c$. However, after many numerical experiments, I find the choice of $a$ to be irrelevant in that respect, and the asymptotic behavior of {$q_n$} is determined by $c$ only.

Is that true? Why? If so, let $C^m$ and $B^m$ be the sets of $c$ such that {$q_n$} is convergent and bounded, respectively.

Question 1: What are $C^m$ and $B^m$ like?

Question 2: Given $c\in B^m$ and $c\notin C^m$, must {$q_n$} be periodic? If so, what periods are possible?

---

Some examples:
[image]
$m=8$, $c=(0.1811,    0.0611,    0.0933,    0.0547,   -0.7898,    0.0772,    0.1410,    0.1435)$
[image]
same as above, with -0.7898 changed to -0.7890
[image]
$m=13$, $c=(0.0869, 0.0786, 0.1296, 0.0879, 0.0609, 0.0444, 0.0963, 0.0899, 0.0910, 0.0528, 0.0430, -1.0020, 0.0317)$
[image]
same as above, with -1.0020 changed to -1.

Comment: Guess you meant $q$ (not $a$) in the summation part. That's a [linear homogeneous recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). If you read up on the general solution, the $c$ coefficients determine the roots of the characteristic polynomial, while the $a$ initial values determine the coefficients of the linear combination of powers (or at least that's the case in the absence of multiple roots).

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. That's right. I've fixed the typo.